# Using Static Variables in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Why is it not possible to use a static Variable from a static class inside a view?

For example, lets say you have a Settings Class:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static string SystemColor
    {
        get { return Properties.Settings.Default.SystemColor; }
    }
}
```

Why wouldn't you be able to call it in a view?

like so

```
@using AppName.Models
<html>
<div ><h1 style="color:@GlobalVariables.SystemColor">System Color</h1></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you *can* access static variables from inside a view in ASP.NET MVC, if you include the class' namespace with the appropriate `using` statement:

```
@using WhateverNamespaceGlobalVariablesIsIn
```

More importantly, you shouldn't be accessing static variables directly from views anyway. In keeping with the MVC pattern, all of your view's data should be accessible in your view model:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.SystemColor = GlobalVariables.SystemColor;
    ...
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

<div>
    <h1 style="color:@(Model.SystemColor)">System Color</h1>
</div>
```

If you need to do this in your layout file, you can use `RenderAction` to call a controller action and return a partial view instead. The partial can then be typed to `MyViewModel`, which can be used as above.

Comment: So you shouldn't because of conforming to the MVC pattern? is that the main reason why?

Comment: As far as I know, you *can* use static variables in views as long as you include the namespace of the class with `@using`. You shouldn't, though.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, I just didn't want to have to go create viewmodels for everything even when I wasn't passing a viewmodel. Like for example I have a customer list that just passed a list of customer model.

Comment: If it is something like a global color, as in the question, what is the point of going through all of the extra work just to expose it in the model?  How is that better than using the static?

Comment: I'm with this, seems silly and over the top to pass it in a variable - and we are discouraged of making 'magic' numbers/variables.

Comment: you can't include an `static` class, this answer is not working

Comment: You should try to avoid this. If you app is ever growing to somewhat big at some point you might want to get rid of Static classes, especially in views. You can't mock them, can't inject anything there (only by using service locator), they are untestable. This solution might look like the easiest to implement at first glance but it'll cost you a fortune afterall.

Answer (score 14):

your global class should be like

```
public class GlobalVariables
{
    public static string SystemColor
    {
        get { return Properties.Settings.Default.SystemColor; }
    }
}
```

and in page @**AppName**.GlobalVariables.SystemColor **appname** replace by namespace of global class

```
@using AppName.Models
<html>
<div ><h1 style="color:@AppName.GlobalVariables.SystemColor">System Color</h1></div>
</html>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can access static variables in the view. There are three ways of doing this:

1) As Ant P suggests, include using statement in the view. Given that the namespace of the `GlobalVariables` class is `AppName.GlobalVariables`:

```html
@using AppName.GlobalVariables
<html>
    <div ><h1 style="color:@GlobalVariables.SystemColor">System Color</h1></div>
</html>
```

2) Another way is to directly use the namespace in the line where you want to access variable:

```html
<div ><h1 style="color:@AppName.GlobalVariables.SystemColor">System Color</h1></div>
```

3) Finally, you can add needed namespace to the web.config file under Views folder:

```html
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      <add namespace="AppName.GlobalVariables" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

---

As for the sticking the variable in the Model and passing it to the View from there... indeed it conforms to the MVC pattern and assures separation of concerns and all that goodness. But in my opinion in some cases "sticking to the pattern" is taken to the level of absurd. In your case I'd just access this variable from the view.