# MVC logic - How do I pull a static global variable to my views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please bear with me, I am completely new to the MVC setup but reasonable with c#

Aim: I want to be able to refer to a global, static, immutable string value that is defined once in my asp.net mvc project and used in various places around the site (e.g. the site name) in the cshtml files (About, Contact, _Layout etc.)

I've tried:

1) [Adding a variable using object runat global asax file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178594(v=vs.140)) but this is a c#-type file so not sure how I can be adding html code. If I use a `public string s()` method I still don't know how to call it in my _Layout.cshtml file

2) Creating a `public static class myGlobalVariables` file in the controllers folder (even though I'm sure that's not the place for it) but, still, can't access it in the .cshtml files

3) Trying to hi-jack the ViewBag and implement a new property (?) for it? but I don't really know how the ViewBag works.

4) Adding a key/value pair to the `appSettings` within `Web.config` but again, I can't seem to find this variable when wanting to pull it to the _Layout.cshtml

**Edit**: I'm using a default MVC setup in VS2017 Community

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17272185/9695286 here `AppName` is namespace.

Comment: Yes! That's it, thanks!

Comment: Also, these static variables would be better off in `Models` as opposed to controller yes? Because it's data.

Comment: It shouldn't be in `Model` or `Controller`. They should be in some common stand alone class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Static Variables in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271827/using-static-variables-in-razor)