# .net mvc can I use razor within razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Nutshell:**

How can I put an `@Html.Action` within and `@Html.ActionLink` ?

E.g using a default Visual Studio 2017 MVC project, there's a line in the _Layout.cshtml:

`@Html.ActionLink("Application Name" , "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })`

But I want it to be:

`@Html.ActionLink(@Html.Action("SiteName") , "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })`

where `Action("SiteName")` pulls in the .cshtml which is literally just a string with my site name in?!? Is this possible? Or can I maybe define a string via the `Action` somewhere at the start of my `_Layout` and put that in the `ActionLink` ?

**History:**

So I spent a while finding out how to have a global variable that I can call anywhere in my MVC `View` ([My old question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756454/mvc-logic-how-do-i-pull-a-static-global-variable-to-my-views) which lead to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271827/using-static-variables-in-razor/17272185#17272185)

With the idea from the first answer, info from [this site](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) and with the noble aim of trying to stick to "the pattern" I've ended up creating

a `ViewModel`

```
public class SSVs
{
    public string SiteName { get; }
}
```

and a PartialView

```
SiteName.cshtml
```

-This literally contains a string saying "My Site Name"

Now I'm introducing this dotted around my `_Layout.cshtml` using `@Html.Action("SiteName")`

It works! Great, and all I have to do to update every reference to my site name is change the SiteName.cshtml

Now I'm thinking sticking to "The pattern" was completely over the top and I need a much simpler way to hold some global variables...

Comment: `@Html.Action` purpose is to call a specific action provided as its parameter. Since you have `actionName` and `controllerName` parameters in `@Html.ActionLink` helper, then `@Html.Action` inside `@Html.ActionLink` deemed unnecessary. If you want to pass site name as link text, do so with viewmodel property instead.

Comment: You can use a constant such as `Site.Name` where the class `Site` contains a constant string `Name`. `@Html.ActionLink(NameSpace.Site.Name , "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })` Your wanted approach looks weird tbh.

Comment: Yes it is weird. I don't understand it. I don't understand MVC, really, but I'm trying to figure it out, but doing simple things seems to be convoluted and overwork.

Comment: If I refer to `Site.Name` then this class has to be static, yes? This is what one of the answers above was teaching to avoid. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Using constants doesn't require your class to be static. In unit testing perceptive, static is frowned upon as it can't be tested. As for using static or constants for your site's name, do you need to test it? You have to weigh in your options.

Comment: I guess for some simple strings then testing would be completely unnecessary so that's great. Not sure how I'd pull a constant from a class without instantiating it but I'll have a look! Thanks for the advice!