# I have methods that get data from a service reference API. How do I get that data to display on a Razor page?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I have a working .NET Core 2.1 Console application that displays character information on screen.  The data is gathered from Service References that make calls to an API.

I now want to make it a web application instead.  So I created a new .NET Core 2.1 Web application with Razor (cshtml) in Visual Studio 2017.

I added all the methods and service references from the console application and ironed out all the errors.

So I now have a web app that builds, but it just displays the "dummy ASP.NET Core Sample data" pages that were automatically created when I created the project.

But I am not sure how to get my methods to display the data.  Previously, I would just use "Console.WriteLine" like this:

```
    public static void PrintCharacter(Character pc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Character Name =  " + pc.Name);
        ListCharactersResponse response = GetCharacter(pc.Id);

        foreach (Attribute attr in response.Results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Character Attributes: " + attr.Strength + " | " + attr.Intelligence + " | " + GetMagicPoints(attr.Intelligence, attr.Wisdom));
        }

    }
```

Looking through the sample pages that were generated, I see stuff like this:

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = "Your application description page.";
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to get my data from my methods, like PrintCharacter above, into the .cshtml pages.

Is there something else I need to have Visual Studio do?  Or do I need to write some type of method that displays the data on a webpage instead of console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Razor Pages you just need to use `@Model.Message` in view to display the variable defined directly in PageModel.
`ViewData` is enable while `ViewBag` is not allowed.Refer to [ViewData in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/viewdata).

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
       Message = "Your application description page.";
       ViewData["message"] = "test message";
    }
}
```

View

```
@page
@model AboutModel
<h1>@ViewData["message"]</h1>
<h1>@Model.Message</h1>
```

Update:

To read data from static method in view , you need to return the data from the method and know its namespace to call it. Refer to [Using Static Variables in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271827/using-static-variables-in-razor).

For example,create a static method in a class of ConsoleApp.

```
public class ConsoleClass
{
    public static List<string> PrintCharacter(Character pc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Character Name =  " + pc.Name);
        ListCharactersResponse response = GetCharacter(pc.Id);
        List<string> Test = new List<string>();

        foreach (Attribute attr in response.Results)
        {
            Test.Add("Character Attributes: " + attr.Strength + " | " + attr.Intelligence + " | " + GetMagicPoints(attr.Intelligence, attr.Wisdom));
        }
        return Test;
   }
}
```

In PageModel where we need to call the method:

```
[BindProperty]
public Character Character { get; set; }
public List<string> DataStored { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    DataStored = ConsoleApp.ConsoleClass.PrintCharacter(Character);//use correct namespace
}
```

In View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DataStored)
{
   <h3>@item</h3>
}
```

You could also call the static method directly in the view like:

```
@foreach (var item in ConsoleApp.ConsoleClass.PrintCharacter(Model.Character))
{
   <h3>@item</h3>
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I was trying to ask how to get the data from my PrintCharacter method to display on a website. Thanks

Comment: I am late.I update the reply and have tested it to call method in consoleApp.